# File written while app is in the background is not saved

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an app that can receive messages/files while it's on the background via webRTC.

When a file is received, I write it to disk. But when trying to access it later (even between app launches) that file doesn't exist.

User's document folder has `NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication` attribute.

I've tried to create the file on disk using `NSData`'s `[writeToURL:options:error:]`, `[writeToFile:options:error:]`; `NSFileManager`'s `[createFileAtPath:contents:attributes:]` and also `NSFileHandle`'s methods.

All of them successfully create the file at the designated path/url. Right after creation I check whether file exists with `NSFileManager`'s `[attributesOfItemAtPath:error:]` which shows me the following:

```
attributes: { 
   NSFileCreationDate = "2018-05-07 18:47:50 +0000";
   NSFileExtensionHidden = 0;
   NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID = 501;
   NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName = mobile;
   NSFileModificationDate = "2018-05-07 18:47:50 +0000";
   NSFileOwnerAccountID = 501;
   NSFileOwnerAccountName = mobile;
   NSFilePosixPermissions = 420;
   NSFileProtectionKey = NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication;
   NSFileReferenceCount = 1;
   NSFileSize = 92156;
   NSFileSystemFileNumber = 695101;
   NSFileSystemNumber = 16777219;
   NSFileType = NSFileTypeRegular;
}
```

`[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[fileURL path]]` also shows me that the file exists after write.

Considering it could be a threading problem, I've also tried to write that file putting it on a main thread block, but result is the same. First file seems to be written but, when trying to access it afterwards it's like it never was.

Is there anything I could be missing?

edit: Added function I use to write.

```
- (void) saveFileData:(NSData *)fileData completionHandler:(void(^)(BOOL success))completionHandler {
   NSURL *fileURL = [self fileURL];

   NSError *error = nil;
   [fileData writeToURL:fileURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

   if (error) {
      ZLogError(ZLogTypeFile, @"[%@] could not be saved: %@", self.fileKey, error);
      completionHandler(NO);
      return;
   }

   ZLogDebug(ZLogTypeFile, @"<file: %@> exists after write:%d", fileURL, [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[fileURL path]]);
   NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[fileURL path] error:&error];
   ZLogDebug(ZLogTypeFile, @"attributes: %@", attributes);

   completionHandler(YES);
}
```

output comes as (where Documents is the users `NSDocumentDirectory` in the app)

```
[file: /Documents/57/Downloads/Images/9d1687ab5f4374a2c00429a24316b5ccd3fb0a67.png] exists after write:1
```

and getting the file (an image):

```
- (UIImage *) imageFromURL:(NSURL *)imageURL {
   BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[imageURL path]];

   if (!fileExists) {
      ZLogDebug(ZLogTypeFile, @"[file: %@] exists: %d", imageURL, fileExists);
      return nil;
   }

   return [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];
}
```

in log (note I've taken out the long path before Documents directory just here):

```
[file: /Documents/57/Downloads/Images/9d1687ab5f4374a2c00429a24316b5ccd3fb0a67.png] exists: 1
```

Comment: Try making sure your device is in unlocked state. Or try removing the passcode and check if it works as intended.

Comment: That's the first test I did just to be on the safe side and it still didn't work as intended.

Comment: What's the path you're writing the file to? Can you share the code that checks that the file exists for the 2nd time? Is this code also running in background? I doubt that the file can magically disappear.

Comment: I've edited the question with some extra information. I know the data is actually received because I send the `NSData` object it right after saving it successfully to a `UserNotification` as `UNNotificationAttachment`. When I open the app after tapping on that notification (or even without tapping it a few hours later). I see that the file is not there, but still in logs I see that it was written originally.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is years later, but i had the same issue, reproducible on iOS 13 up to 17.

Context : I have an image that is saved while the app is in background, then present a notification showing the image. The image does exist after being saved, then disappears.

First fix: I added a watcher to check the presence of my file every 0.5s and resave it after it disappears. It works, the file disappears quite quickly and can be saved again just as quickly, but it is an ugly fix.

The real commonality between our issues seems to be the use of `UNNotificationAttachment`. Turns out, if i don't add the attachment to my notification, the file stays!

After a bit of searching i found the following bit of documentation : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49367332/1439489

> The system validates the content of attached files before scheduling the corresponding notification request. If an attached file is corrupted, invalid, or of an unsupported file type, the notification request is not scheduled for delivery. Once validated, attached files are moved into the attachment data store so that they can be accessed by the appropriate processes. Attachments located inside an app’s bundle are copied instead of moved.

iOS will move the saved image to present its notification, removing it from the app documents directory.

Second fix: I have decided to store a copy of the file in a temporary directory instead.