# Sharing files using iOS App Group container between Notification Service and application (flutter)

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter, apple-push-notifications

- Application written in flutter
- Using [ios_app_group](https://pub.dev/packages/ios_app_group) plugin to obtain app group container path
- Notification service downloads a picture
- Obtains the app group container location using the following objective C code:

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *groupURL = [fileManager containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:AppGroupName];
```

(where AppGroupName is the app group name in use) and saves the URL to the app group user defaults.

- When the application starts (after Notification service saved an image), it looks for the image in the same location **but can't find it.**

I have compared the locations and found them identical. The image is displayed well on the notification (which means file was correctly downloaded).

Any ideas/help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if this is something you ran into or if my issue is even similar. Any chance you have insight into my issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65239077/flutter-ios-file-sharing-cannot-open-shared-file

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that the image downloaded was use for the notification itself, to be displayed:

```
UNNotificationAttachment *icon = [UNNotificationAttachment attachmentWithIdentifier:@"" URL:absoluteAttachmentURL options:nil error:&error];
(self.bestAttemptContent.attachments = @[icon];)
```

This mechanism moves the file to a different folder, so later when application starts it is not found.
More information is found here: [Will iOS Notification Service Extension delete attached file from device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45999859/will-ios-notification-service-extension-delete-attached-file-from-device)